# Rails, Simple Form and namespaced resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, nested

I'm trying to learn how to use namespaced folders in my Rails 5 app.

I use simple form for forms.

I have models for User and Profile.

The associations are:

User

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

Profile

```
belongs_to :user
```

In my controllers, I have app/controllers/users/profiles_controller.rb

That has:

```
class Users::ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized

  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
    authorize @profiles
  end

  def show
    # debugger
  end

def new
    @profile = Profile.new
    authorize @profile
end

def edit
end

def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    authorize @profile

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update

    # Rails.logger.info "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    # Rails.logger.info successful.inspect
    # user=@profile.user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @profile.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to profiles_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  private
    def set_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
      authorize @profile
    end

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit( :title, :hero, :avatar, :overview,  :occupation, :external_profile )
    end
end
```

In my views I have a similar folder structure. I have app/views/users/profiles. That folder has a partial called _header.html.erb, a _form.html.erb and an edit.html.erb

I render header.html.erb from my users/show.html.erb file. That works fine. However, I can't figure out how to get the edit profile link to work.

In my _header.html.erb partial I have:

```
 <%= link_to "Update your profile", edit_profile_path(:user, @profile.id) %>
```

I've tried at least 20 variations on this line - but none of them work to get to the users/profiles/edit view.

My rake routes show me:

```
user_profiles GET      /users/:user_id/profiles(.:format)         users/profiles#index
                                 POST     /users/:user_id/profiles(.:format)         users/profiles#create
                new_user_profile GET      /users/:user_id/profiles/new(.:format)     users/profiles#new
                    edit_profile GET      /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)               users/profiles#edit
                         profile GET      /profiles/:id(.:format)                    users/profiles#show
                                 PATCH    /profiles/:id(.:format)                    users/profiles#update
                                 PUT      /profiles/:id(.:format)                    users/profiles#update
                                 DELETE   /profiles/:id(.:format)                    users/profiles#destroy
```

To my eye, the key line from this is:

```
edit_profile GET      /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)               users/profiles#edit
```

I just don't understand what's going wrong. I think this should mean that I can write:

```
<%= link_to "Update your profile", edit_profile_path(@profile) %>
```

That doesnt work either.

Each of the errors point to the first line of my profiles form, which has:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:user, @profile] do |f| %>
```

I wrote ":user" in this line because namespaced advice is to do this.

In my routes.rb file, I have:

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
    scope module: :users do
      resources :assign_roles
      resources :identities
      resources :profiles
      resources :settings
    end
  end
```

Can anyone help me understand what is required to plug this in?

Comment: Since you are using `shallow: true` on parent element, I think only `simple_form_for @profile` will be enough, no need of `user` namespace. Can you try and let me know ?

Comment: <%= simple_form_for(@profile) do |f| %> gives an error that says: No route matches [GET] "/profile/new"

Comment: ya, I got it. Its because the new profile route is different. It should be fixed if you nest it for user .Since every profile is for a user you have to do it like `simple_form_for [@user, @profile]` . Here `@user` is the user for which you are making profile. Not just a namespace

Comment: that isn't working either. i don't understand the rules for this. Now I have: new_user_profile_path GET /users/:user_id/profiles/new(.:format) 
users/profiles#new

edit_profile_path GET /profiles/:id/edit(.:format) 
users/profiles#edit

Comment: i can't get the new or edit profile forms to render